# Alfresco contentstore selection

Tags: alfresco

This is regarding a alfresco multiple content store .

I believe , we can create multiple contentstore location , other than default one. ($ALF_DATA/contentstore/2019) . In case if i have multiple contentsore defined using config file(‘content-store-selector-context.xml’ ), Is there a way to specify or select contentstore while uploading files to alfresco . for ex – if i have following config ,

D:/storeB

How can i specify document to be uploaded to [D:/storeB/2019 ] location , instead of default location ($ALF_DATA/contentstore/2019)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RTFM? Documentation [Using the new content store](https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/concepts/store-using.html) states, you need to add the aspect `cm:storeSelector` and set the property `cm:storeName`
This could be done by Skript, rule or extension.

Comment: Also note that in the content store selector context file you are able to specify a default content store. The aspect is not required when you are happy with the default. https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/tasks/store-filestore-define.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have Enterprise version, you have that OOTB.
https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/store-manage-content.html

If you're on community, I'd suggest using https://github.com/Acosix/alfresco-simple-content-stores.

Comment: Hi  , thanks for the response. 

I am using Alfresco EE 6.x  . I understand we can configure multiple content store ($ALF_DATA/contentstore/2019). But while uploading the document it always goes to default content store location .

As i mentioned im my initial query,  how do i specify contentstore while uploading the docuement through Alfresco share(application UI ) .  If i have multiple store configured ( storeA & storeB). How we can i specify uploaded document to be stored in storeA or storeB.